# Bootstrap datepicker function is not working on modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use datepicker that show on modal. Calendar is coming but datepicker options is not working. My code is,

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
   autoclose:true,
   format:'dd-mm-yyyy',
   endDate:today,
   todayHighlight:true,
   orientation:"bottom",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="actionItemModalWrap" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modifiedDataModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-extra-lg" role="document">
       <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
               <h1 class="myriadproRegular textAlignCenter">Actions</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #ecefef !important;">
           <div id='actionItemContentWrapper'>
             <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="width:260px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should i do to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you initialized `date` class for `input`?

Comment: what does your console say on the error?

Comment: `ReferenceError: today is not defined` what is today?

Answer (score 0):

What `datepicker` do you use? In your snippet, you have an error in `endDate` because `today` variable has not been initialized

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
   autoclose:true,
   format:'dd-mm-yyyy',
   endDate: new Date(),
   todayHighlight:true,
   orientation:"bottom",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="actionItemModalWrap" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modifiedDataModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-extra-lg" role="document">
       <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
               <h1 class="myriadproRegular textAlignCenter">Actions</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #ecefef !important;">
           <div id='actionItemContentWrapper'>
             <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="width:260px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-initialize the date picker when you try to call the modal because modal is a dynamic function and it needs to reinitialize any functionality inside your modal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display `datepicker` in `model` popup dialod, Use : bootstrap-datepicker.js

Please check below example:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    }).datepicker('update', new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Actions
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #ecefef !important;">
                <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```